# Programmatically install a service without printing debug info

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, service, windows-services

I'm using this snippet to programatically install a service:

C#:

```
public static void InstallService(string filepath, 
                                 string svcName, 
                                 string displayName = "", 
                                 string description = "", 
                                 ServiceStartMode startType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic,
                                 ServiceAccount account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem, 
                                 string username = "", 
                                 string password = "")
{
    using (ServiceProcessInstaller installer = new ServiceProcessInstaller()) {

        using (ServiceInstaller svc = new ServiceInstaller()) {

            InstallContext context = new InstallContext("", { string.Format("/assemblypath={0}", filepath) });

            installer.Account = account;
            installer.Username = username;
            installer.Password = password;

            svc.Context = context;
            svc.DisplayName = displayName;
            svc.Description = description;
            svc.ServiceName = svcName;
            svc.StartType = startType;
            svc.Parent = installer;

            ListDictionary state = new ListDictionary();
            svc.Install(state);
            state.Clear();

        }

    }

}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//=======================================================
```

Vb.Net (original):

```
Public Shared Sub InstallService(ByVal filepath As String,
                                 ByVal svcName As String,
                                 Optional ByVal displayName As String = "",
                                 Optional ByVal description As String = "",
                                 Optional ByVal startType As ServiceStartMode = ServiceStartMode.Automatic,
                                 Optional ByVal account As ServiceAccount = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem,
                                 Optional ByVal username As String = "",
                                 Optional ByVal password As String = "")

    Using installer As New ServiceProcessInstaller

        Using svc As New ServiceInstaller

            Dim context As New InstallContext("", {String.Format("/assemblypath={0}", filepath)})

            installer.Account = account
            installer.Username = username
            installer.Password = password

            svc.Context = context
            svc.DisplayName = displayName
            svc.Description = description
            svc.ServiceName = svcName
            svc.StartType = startType
            svc.Parent = installer

            Dim state As New ListDictionary
            svc.Install(state)
            state.Clear()

        End Using

    End Using

End Sub
```

The problem is that when calling that method, the installation status is written in the debug console of the application:

> Installing service...
>
> Service has been successfully installed.
>
> Creating EventLog source in log Application...

I'm not sure in which manner what member of those classes requests to print that info, just its possibly to disable that undesired verbosity?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LogToConsole=false` command line parameter when you are instantiating InstallContext as below...

```
InstallContext context = new InstallContext("", { string.Format("/assemblypath={0} /LogToConsole=false", filepath) });
```

References:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installcontext_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thankyou, but for whatever reason didn't worked that parameter, it still shows the info :(.

Comment: Try this: InstallContext context = new InstallContext("", { string.Format("/LogToConsole=false {0}", filepath) });

Comment: Check different ways parameters are given in the InstallUtil.exe documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. It should work.

Comment: Why there isn't any **AssemblyPath** parameter documented?, are you sure the .net wrapper uses the same parameter namings?. Seems that the **AssemblyPath** should be the first parameter, because if I change the order of the parameters it throws an **InvalidOperationException** saying that cant get the service name (path).

Comment: I accept the solution because the hints, but what really worked for me is only using the `Parameters` property in this way: `context.Parameters.Add("LogToConsole", "False")` and `context.Parameters.Add("AssemblyPath", String.Format("""{0}""", filepath))` instead of using the constructor overload. Thanks again.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Thanks for sharing back. I appreciate it.